# db_table option does not work in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I want to remove the app label from the table name hence i have a extremely simple web application.

I am using following model:

```
class Gender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'gender'
```

The result is not quite as expected:

```
>>> Gender.objects.all()
ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'project.gender' doesn't exist")
```

Why is the meta option not working?

I am using Django 1.6.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`db_table` option gives a flexibility to user for specifying a database table name.

From the error it looks like that table `gender` does not exist in database. That means after specifying this option you haven't performed `syncdb`. Please do a `syncdb` or if you are using south then `schemamigration`.

Comment: Since `syncdb` is not available anymore, I use `python manage.py migrate` but it just creates all the necessary tables on database. The problem remain same for me. 

Is there any ways to use existing database on a new django apps?

Comment: Don't know if I have understood your problem very well but if you want to use exisiting tables then use command `python manage.py inspectdb`, this will create models for the tables in database and display them.

Comment: @tisuchi How did you fix your issue in the end? By using inspectdb?

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution, if you want to change you model name using like this..

```
class Gender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'gender'
```

after that you have to maigrate your model again

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`